# GDAL 1.11.4 портит растры на сервере

Tags: gdal

Диспозиция такова: Есть сервер Centos6, на нём стоит apache, на котором крутится сайт. Пользователь, зашедший на страницу, может загрузить туда растр, любого формата, который поддерживает GDAL(1.11.4), обычно это jpeg. После чего, растр конвертируется в GeoTiff через утилиту gdal_translate(вызовом из питона), публикуется на геосервере, после чего показывается через OpenLayers.

Вместо использования вызова консольных утилит, решил написать свою процедуру конвертирования в GeoTiff с индексированной палитрой. Код практически один в один взят из утилиты rgb2pct.py, и он работает, но... часто в результате получаем испорченный растр. Испорченный, это значит чёрные квадраты и полосы, или негатив растра, или цветные полосы.

Вот пример, и это самый корректный вариант из всех не корректных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вернуть назад конвертирование через вызов консольной утилиты, то всегда получаем корректный растр. Я предпологал, что данные не успевают из кеша попасть на диск, и пробовал ставить задержку, и иногда это помогало. Ещё грешил на многопоточность, но опция `NUM_THREADS=4`, как оказалось, в версии GDAL 1.11.4 не работает. Осталось погрешить на то, что версия библиотеки старая. Локально, на десктопе, даже с этой же версией, я такого получить не смог.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным и знает как забороть, то я был бы рад услышать способ решения.

Вот код конвертирования

```
out_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outdataset = out_driver.Create(target_file, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte,
                                   options=[
                                       'COMPRESS=LZW',
                                       'TFW=YES',
                                       'INTERLEAVE=BAND',
                                       'NUM_THREADS=4',
                                       'PROFILE=GeoTIFF',
                                       'BIGTIFF=IF_NEEDED',
                                       'TILED=YES',
                                       'BLOCKXSIZE=256',
                                       'BLOCKYSIZE=256'])

ct = gdal.ColorTable()
err = gdal.ComputeMedianCutPCT(ds.GetRasterBand(1),
                                       ds.GetRasterBand(2),
                                       ds.GetRasterBand(3),
                                       256, ct,
                                       None,
                                       None)

outdataset.GetRasterBand(1).SetRasterColorTable(ct)

outdataset.SetProjection(srs_wkt)
outdataset.SetGeoTransform(dt_new)

err = gdal.DitherRGB2PCT(ds.GetRasterBand(1),
                                 ds.GetRasterBand(2),
                                 ds.GetRasterBand(3),
                                 outdataset.GetRasterBand(1),
                                 ct,
                                 None,
                                 None)
outdataset.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(255)

outdataset.FlushCache()
outdataset = None
ds = None
```